# XAMPP USB Lite - How to change or upgrade MySQL 5.5 to 5.6?

Tags: mysql, xampp, upgrade

Since XAMPP supports only MySQL 5.5, I would like to upgrade the MySQL server to version 5.6 (beta) in the currently stable 1.7.7, or 1.8.1 version of XAMPP.

Can I do that? If so, how?

(Just to clarify it: coping and switching the `mysql` folder won't make it.)

Comment: Look into comments below my answer. I managed to prove you, that simple copy & folder switch does the job and is enough to upgrade MySQL on-board XAMPP from 5.1.41 to 5.6.10. However there are slight side effects (like need to start `mysqld` manually).

Comment: And that is why your answer is not a solution. The "slight side effect" (need to start `mysqld`) is what we wish to avoid. We want to integrate the new 5.6 version into XAMPP (both control panel), just like the original bundled version. Everyone can download, copy a new MySQL installation and run the MySQL demon.

Comment: You have asked for an instruction to upgrade MySQL inside XAMPP. I provided one to you, by which I also negated your claim -- coping and switching the `mysql` folder **does** make it. Now, you're referring only to problems with starting `mysqld`. This is completely beyond what question covers. You asked about upgrade, not about how to start `mysqld` after upgrade. But, OK, I see your point and accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the perfect way of doing it without any side affects and also works perfectly with xampp control panel...

before you begin, make sure you backup your databases to files and also export all users to a file
be sure to stop mysql there is no need to uninstall the service

Step 1: Download the new version on MySQL install version or zip.(install version prefered since it is considerably smaller)

Step 2: Install MySQL to C:\TEMP. Install only the MySQL server

Step 3:Do not run advance options. do not let it install service. no configuration is required.

Step 4: Go to C:\TEMP, look for installation and copy the following folders "bin, include, lib, share, support-files". be absolutely certain not to copy data
Once copied, go to your xampp folder, rename mysql folder to mysql_old. create new mysql folder then paste the contents that were copied

Step 5: Go to mysql_old and copy the data folder and paste it into your new mysql folder as well

Step 6: go to the bin folder within mysql that is located within xampp and create a blank my.ini file.
If you are upgrading to version 5.6.11 which is what I did, then all you have to do is write a few commands which I have at the bottom of this instruction

step 7: click start next to MySQL on the xampp control panel and it should start normally assuming to you followed to instructions properly.
Once done, you can uninstall the mysql package that you had installed to C:\TEMP
Any questions or problems, message me or post back!

BY WAY, the key is having a proper my.ini file

here is mine:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/tmp/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/tmp/mysql.sock"
pid_file = mysql.pid

skip-federated
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

basedir="C:/xampp/mysql"
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"

log-output = FILE
log-error = mysql_error.log
general-log
general_log_file = mysql_general.log
slow-query-log
slow_query_log_file = mysql_slow.log

default-time-zone = -5:00
long_query_time = 2
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin"
server-id = 2

#ft_stopword_file = "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql_ft_stopword_file.ini"
ft_min_word_len = 3
ft_max_word_len = 50

character-sets-dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

innodb_ft_max_token_size = 50
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 3
innodb_ft_enable_stopword = off

key_buffer_size = 8M

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 4M
query_cache_limit = 4M

default-storage-engine = InnoDB

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: It's also recommended to run `mysql_upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the steps listed above and I was able to start mysql NOT from the xampp control panel but from Windows Control Panel -> Systems and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Component Services (Or simply search for component services on windows search). Once you have launched component services, click "services". It will list all the services on your computer. Look for mysql, click on it and click "start". That did the magic for me!! Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

the safest and most xampp-compatible way, i did following for upgrading  :

first of all, stop your existing Xampp processes like Apache and MySQL and other MySQL related Xampp installed services. just stop the services, DONT uninstall them.

1) look which MySQL-version you want/need to upgrade to. Some packages like MOODLE 1.7+ requires a minimum MySQL version ( f.e. 5.5.31 ).

2) download the Xampp installer which includes the MySQL version which you want to upgrade to. the list of Xampp version an which MySQL version they includes, you can find [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/).

3) install the new version of Xampp on another pc

4) on this new install of Xampp on the other pc, go to c:/xampp/mysql  and COPY the following maps :

- bin
- include
- lib
- share

5) on your old xampp machine, rename the c:/xampp/mysql map to f.e. c:/xampp/mysql_backup and make a new empty map c:/xampp/mysql

6) now PASTE the previous COPIED maps from 4) above, in this new c:/xampp/mysql  map.

7) go to c:/xampp/mysql_backup map and copy the BIN map, and past it in c:/xampp/mysql

8) compare and complete/modify a few settings ( like buffer sizes or DIR locations)  in the new my.ini file which is located in c:/xampp/mysql/bin map with the old my.ini file which is in c:/xampp/mysql_backup/bin.

don't delete the c:/xampp/mysql_backup map too fast, errors can occur later on, so you can consult some files later on perhaps. consider it as a backup.

start PHP and MySQL through the Xampp control panel, and everything should work as before.
the advantage of this method, is that you use a MySQL build which is 100% compatible with Xampp CP and phpmyadmin.

Using a MySQL msi-installer can give some problems to get it working. the advantage though, is that you can upgrade it very easy in the future, using an updated MySQL msi-installer just with a few clicks, instead of copy-pasting maps and files ...

Answer (score -1):

You can and you shouldn't encounter any problems. AFAIK whole XAMPP is build from blocks of separate services. MySQL resides (whole, with data, configuration, etc.) in mysql subfolder. I must admit, that I'm writing theoretically, cause I haven't been doing something like that (but I'm about to update phpMyAdmin and will use the same steps). But I would follow these steps:

1. Turn off everything about XAMPP (all servers you've started up).
2. If you have MySQL installed as service (tick "Svc" next to "MySQL" checked) -- uninstall it (uncheck).
3. Rename "mysql" folder inside XAMPP to "mysql_old" or something similar,
4. Create new "mysql" folder and install freshly new MySQL into it, using installer or guide provided by MySQL.
5. Configure, what you have to configure (inside MySQL), startup MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel or by other ways, install it as a service (mark "Svc" checkbox), if you wish so.
6. Check, if everything is OK. If yes, delete "mysql_old" folder from your XAMPP installation.

As for data migration (if you have any), you can do this by either exporting data from old MySQL (before installing new version, i.e. before executing above steps) using phpMyAdmin or similar tool and then importing it into new version of MySQL. Or you can consider a bruteforce mode, that is - copying whole contents of mysql_old/data folder to mysql/data folder. But no guarantee, this will work.

Comment: Actually, this is not working. I've already tried this before posting the issue! All you can do is, to copy a new MySQL somewhere else, and start the `mysqld`. The XAMPP control application is ignored this case.

Comment: I must check it at home. But before that, I simply can't believe you. XAMPP is a package, built out of blocks and you can simply change one of this blocks. Since MySQL resides inside `mysql` folder I don't see, why you could have any problems removing it and uncompressing newer version of MySQL in it's place. BTW: When asking, write what you have already done! People won't waste time repeating steps already undertaken by you and your question get more attention, as it will be clearly visible that you have done something yourself, not just asking and waiting for help (homework-type question).

Comment: I thought it's a trivial solution to copy and paste a newly downloaded `mysql` folder, and I used to avoid repeating or mentioning trivia over and over again. Also, I'm looking for a solution, e.i. a workaround which, a StackOverflow user knows and dare to share with me. Deliberately didn't want to ask anyone to "try steps" nor "solve" this issue for me, I'm looking for a user who already solved it.

Comment: The problem is with XAMPP unable to start new version of MySQL, not MySQL itself. I have just done, what I wrote in my answer, getting newest MySQL from mysql.com. Then I copied `data`, `scripts` and root folder contents from `mysql_old` to `mysql`. And I managed to run new version of MySQL with `c:\XAMPP\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe`. My application run without problems under new MySQL, all data was restored. With this code: `mysql_connect('srv', 'user', 'pass'); printf ("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());` I managed to verify that my PHP runs under new version of MySQL (5.6.10).

Comment: Of course, new version of MySQL is **enormous**, because XAMPP guys are doing great optimization. For example, only key folders (these, that I had in `mysql_old`) have 931 MB in 5.6.10, while optimized XAMPP edition of 5.1.41 have the same folders with only 75 MB. Entire 5.6.10 edition has 1084 MB, that is nearly 13 times more. For this and for convenience of starting MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel, I decided to stay on 5.1.41. You can ask at Apache Friend's forum, what magic do they made, so you can start `mysqld.exe` manually, but can't start MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel after upgrade.